# C# and ASP.NET - Populate web page textboxes from Dropdownlist using results in a SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web, dropdown

I am trying to populate 2 text boxes using a `dropdownlist` on my web-page however I can't get the code required text boxes to populate

I can confirm that the code stated below works when I use a **button** instead of a **dropdownlist**

I have defined the dropdown list in the `default.aspx` as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Player" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="">Please Select</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>`

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Phocas_WorkBenchConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ID, [PlayerFirstName] + ' ' + [PlayerLastName] as 'Player' FROM [Players]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have created the `C#` code in the `default.aspx.cs` as follows:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-PMSK135\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phocas_WorkBench;Integrated Security=True");
    {
        SqlCommand getFirstName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerFirstName from Players where ID = @PlayerID", sql);
        SqlCommand getLastName = new SqlCommand("Select PlayerLastName from Players where ID = @PlayerID", sql);
        getFirstName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        getLastName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);



        sql.Open(); //Opens Connection to the SQL Database using the definded Connection String. In this case the defined connection string is stored in "sql"
        string getResults = (string)getFirstName.ExecuteScalar();
        TextBox3.Text = getResults;
        getResults = (string)getLastName.ExecuteScalar();
        TextBox4.Text = getResults;
        sql.Close();            
    }
}
```

I am hoping to populate the results from the 2 `SqlCommand` into `textbox3` and `textbox4` with @PlayerID being equal to the results stored in the `dropdownlist` with the `DataValueField="ID"` as `ID` is the Unique identifier

I have tried many different types when trying to replace the variables in the `AddWithValue`. See the ones I have tried below:

- `DropDownList1.text`
- `DropDownList1.DataValueField`
- `DropDownList1.SelectedValue`
- `DropDownList1.SelectedIndex`

However none of the above seem to work.
A nudge in the right direction would be very helpful

Thank you.

Comment: Is your AutoEventWireUp and EnableViewState set to true on the page level?

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` and confirm that it's being executed?